# How do I know which parameters to use with a pretrained Tokenizer?

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I must be missing something ...
I want to use a pretrained model with HuggingFace:

```py
transformer_name = "Geotrend/distilbert-base-fr-cased"  # Or whatever model
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(transformer_name, num_labels=5)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(transformer_name)
```

Now that I have my model and my tokenizer, I need to tokenize my dataset, but I don't know which parameters (padding, truncation, max_length) to use with my Tokenizer.

Some examples just call the tokenizer `tokenizer(data)`, others use truncation only `tokenizer(data, truncation=True)`, and others will use many parameters `tokenizer(data, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt', max_length=512)`.

1. As I am reloading a pretrained Tokenizer, I would have love it to use the same parameters as in the original training process. How do I know which parameters to use ?
2. My understanding is that I always need to truncate my data and leave `max_length` to `None` so that my sequences length will always be lower than the model's maximum length. Is that it ? Does leaving `max_length` to `None` makes it backup on the model's maximum length ?
3. And what should I do with `padding` ? As I am using a `Trainer` object for training with a `DataCollatorWithPadding` should I set `padding` to `False` to reduce the memory impact and let the collator pad my batches ?
4. Final question : what should I do if I use a `TextClassificationPipeline` for inference ? Should I specify these parameters (padding, etc.) ? Will the pipeline handle it for me ?

Comment: So I tested my `TextClassificationPipeline` with a very long sentence and it crashes as the tokenized sequence is too long. So I guess I should at least set truncating to True in my pipeline with `tokenizer_kwargs` in the `__call__` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The choice on whether to use padding and truncation depends on the model you are fine-tuning and on your training process, and not on the pretrained tokenizer.
2. Tranformer-based models have a constraint on the number of tokens the model can process, so generally yes that's it. Yes, when `max_length` is `None` then the maximum acceptable input length for the model is considered. (see [docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__.truncation)).
3. Yes, you should not pad the input sequence if you use `DataCollatorWithPadding`. More about it in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7q5NyFT8REg).
4. As you already noticed, you have to specify them yourself when you pass your input text to the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the provided docs / video :)